# Can an element be outside the computed size of <html>?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an unexpected horizontal bar in my app. It is due to a small gap on the right of my application (the left side is correct, without a gap).

This is a common problem and there are many discussion on the reason (some elements (possibly invisible) extending outside the expected area) and on how to fix that (notably with `overflow: hidden`).

I would like however to find the offending elements rather than use a hack (which fixes the scrollbar but not the gap).

I checked the width of `<html>` with Chrome DevTools and the gap I am seeing is outside of its (`html`'s) area (the blue highlighting corresponds to `<html>` selected in DevTools:

[image]

**Is it possible for an element to extend beyond the *computed* area of `<html>`?** (I am highlighting **computed** here, as opposed to declared)

I then went to measuring the width of the browser. Its value (from edge to edge, that is to the yellow arrow on the right, including the gap) is the same as the computed value of `<html>` provided by DevTools.

When using `overflow: hidden` the scrollbar vanishes but the gap stays (with the same measurements as above).

I am at loss on what could be the reason for this gap. Since `overflow: hidden` fixes the scrollbar, everything would point to an overflow element - but then it should register in the final width of `<html>`

The design is based on Bootstrap and `body` is defined as:

```
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: do you use fixed width? For example, `width:1000px;` , if so then that might be the problem

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru: no, I do not set the width

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru: but in any case, wouldn't that show in DevTools (computed width of `html`)?

Comment: it would show the width size, yeah. Maybe there is a `margin` somewhere in your code that makes the gap, can't really say for sure without any code or something to work on

Comment: @OvidiuUnguru: I am aware of the things which can go wrong (like the margin you mentioned). But in any case the **computed** width of the `<html>` element should reflect all of that.

Comment: "Can an element be outside the computed size of <html>?" Yes, an element may overflow the html element's box. It will still be rendered within the canvas (as defined by CSS, not the html <canvas> element - that's a different thing).

Comment: @BoltClock: sorry, I was not clear with the choice of my words. I meant weather an element, when highlighted in DevTools, can be outside the area highlighted for the `<html>` element. In other words, whether there is an element I can check which would contain all the components (and therefore show the ones which overflow)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add a margin: 0 to the body?

also check if something like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) solves your problem.